# how to catch an int

Tags: .net, exception, il

I am using IL to throw an Int32 and catch it. This is just out of curiosity, I am not trying to achieve anything, so please dont tell me to throw an Exception instead of int.

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  // Code size       40 (0x28)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init (object V_0,
       int32 V_1)
  IL_0000:  nop
  .try
  {
    IL_0001:  nop
    IL_0002:  ldsfld     int32 ConsoleApplication3.Program::i
    IL_0007:  throw
  }  // end .try
  catch [mscorlib]System.Object 
  {
    IL_0008:  stloc.0
    IL_0009:  nop
    IL_000a:  ldstr      "In Object catch"
    IL_000f:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_0014:  nop
    IL_0015:  ldloc.0
    IL_0016:  unbox.any  [mscorlib]System.Int32
    IL_001b:  stloc.1
    IL_001c:  ldloc.1
    IL_001d:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
    IL_0022:  nop
    IL_0023:  nop
    IL_0024:  leave.s    IL_0026
  }  // end handler
  IL_0026:  nop
  IL_0027:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

This does not work, I get the string "In Object catch" but when I try to unbox I get an System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
How can I get the value of what was thrown?

Comment: Write it in C# first then look at the IL?

Comment: cant write it in C#, because C# as a language does not allow throwing int

Comment: Since local 0 is of type System.Exception, it doesn't surprise me that you cannot unbox this as an int.

Comment: it is? is my IL-fu that bad? the .locals directive says it is Exception... Additionally the other local, .1, is declared as bool.

Comment: Changed it .locals init (object V_0,  bool V_1) still same result

Comment: Can you do something like `.GetType().FullName` in IL to determine the dynamic type of the caught object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In version 2.0 of the CLR, when a
>   non–CLS-compliant exception is thrown,
>   the CLR automatically constructs an
>   instance of the
>   RuntimeWrappedException class and
>   initializes its private field to refer
>   to the object that was actually
>   thrown. In effect, the CLR now turns
>   all non–CLS-compliant exceptions into
>   CLS-compliant exceptions.

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (RuntimeWrappedException e)
{
    int a = (int)e.WrappedException;
}
```

Comment: From MSDN :
RuntimeWrappedException Class 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimewrappedexception(v=VS.85).aspx
RuntimeCompatibilityAttribute Class 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimecompatibilityattribute(v=VS.85).aspx